# Univocity CSV parser skip rows based on conditions

Tags: csv, univocity

Is it possible to configure Univocity CSV parser to skip some rows based on predefined conditions like for example values in the cells?

For example I have the following CSV file:

```
name,city
Alex,NY
Mike,London
Dan,Sydney
```

and I'd like to skip from the processing(and remove from resultset) all rows where `city` equal `London`.

I'm unable to find such functionality in documentation. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the ***best solution***, however give a look:

```
    StringReader input = new StringReader(""
        + "name,city\n"
        + "Alex,NY\n"
        + "Mike,London\n"
        + "Dan,Sydney\n");

    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();

    settings.setAutoConfigurationEnabled(true);
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    settings.selectFields("name", "city");

    settings.setProcessor(new RowListProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
            super.rowProcessed(row, context);
            if (row[1].equalsIgnoreCase("London")) {
                context.skipLines(1);
            }
        }
    });

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    parser.beginParsing(input);

    Object[] row;
    while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }

    parser.stopParsing();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iterator approach when going throught file and just skip rows you don't need.
See [iterating approach](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial#using-an-actual-iterator) for more details. Or even [iterating using beans](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_routines.html#iterating-over-bean-instances).